# Custom Scrollbar with position absolute above the content

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, custom-scrolling

Is there a way to have a custom scrollbar for a div with position absolute?

Because of the design layout, I have a content with 100% width and it should pass behind the scroll.

The scroll will appear on mouse over.

I was trying to customize some examples, like this one from codepen:

```
#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-color: #555;
}
```

https://codepen.io/devstreak/pen/dMYgeO

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Just updated my question with the code that I was trying to customize.